# What is the difference between using df.isnull().sum() and df.isnull().count()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading over a notebook on kaggle and I see that someone uses the following code:

```
total = df_train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

percent = (df_train.isnull().sum()/df_train.isnull().count()).sort_values(ascending=False)"
```

So I was wondering what the different use for .sum() and .count() would be since they are both in relation to null values.

Comment: The first case calculates the total number of missing or null values. The second case is to measure the proportion of missing or null values in your dataset. You use one for just counting the values but the other case is to give you an idea of what fraction your dataset has missing values. Have a look at the duplicate post I flagged for more details but simply put, `count` counts the number of rows where `sum` counts the number of values that meet a condition - in this case, it counts how many missing values there are.

Comment: Not a problem at all.  Actually, you can remove `isnull` from the denominator because it returns a dataframe that is the same size but converted to `True/False`.  It's superfluous.  You can just use `count` without `isnull`.